# Using server-side XML Parser to generate HTML content

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xslt

Is it possible using a server side XML parser to have it create an HTML blob that is then included in an existing HTML page?

Answer (score 2):

Is the existing HTML page already being served by the same server? If so, then yes - arguably that's a rough description of what almost all web frameworks do, to a greater or lesser extent: insert some dynamic content within a static template.

Which bit are you concerned about?

Comment: I am building a context sensitive menu system that will live on a number of pages. I have done it before in a somewhat clunky fasion in javascript but am wanting to try out xml and xsl. Basically I am not wanting to head down the wrong path.

Comment: The right course of action will really depend on which web app platform you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages should have XML libraries or parsers available to facilitate this.

For example, PHP has [an XML parser](https://www.php.net/xml).

Write a function using this to take a given XML feed, pretty it up, and spit it out. Then call this function in your HTML page.